# Prove that for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\sqrt[3]{\frac ab} + \sqrt[5]{\frac bc} + \sqrt[7]{\frac ca} > \frac 52$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac ab} + \sqrt[5]{\dfrac bc} + \sqrt[7]{\dfrac ca} > \dfrac 52$.

My thought process along with the proof: Since we're dealing with positive real numbers, I decided to use the AM-GM inequality in a way which lets us get rid of the exponents in the product. That is: $$\sqrt[3]{\dfrac ab} + \sqrt[5]{\dfrac bc} + \sqrt[7]{\dfrac ca} = \sum^3 \dfrac 13\sqrt[3]{\dfrac ab} + \sum^5 \dfrac 15\sqrt[5]{\dfrac bc} + \sum^7 \dfrac 17\sqrt[7]{\dfrac ca},$$ and we apply the AM-GM inequality to get that $$\sum^3 \dfrac 13\sqrt[3]{\dfrac ab} + \sum^5 \dfrac 15\sqrt[5]{\dfrac bc} + \sum^7 \dfrac 17\sqrt[7]{\dfrac ca} \ge 15\sqrt[15]{\frac{1}{3^3 5^5 7^7}}.$$ Then one can notice that it suffices to show that $15\sqrt[15]{\frac{1}{3^3 5^5 7^7}} > \frac 52$, and so I tried to manipulate the right-hand side.

Notice that
\begin{align*}
15\sqrt[15]{\dfrac{1}{3^3 5^5 7^7}} &> \frac{15}{\sqrt[15]{3^1 5^7 7^7}} \\ 
&= \frac{15}{\sqrt[15]{3^1 35^7}} \\
&> \frac{15}{\sqrt[15]{3^1 36^7}} \\
&= \frac{15}{\sqrt[15]{3^1 6^{14}}} \\
&> \frac{15}{\sqrt[15]{6^{15}}} \\
&= \frac{15}{6} \\
&= \frac{5}{2},
\end{align*} and so we should be done.

Comment: This seems fine to me, well done! Do you have any question?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I just wanted someone to verify the correctness of the proof and also give any suggestions.